# What should I use as an Access Control Object in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, acl, cakephp-2.4

I am quite new to ACL

The website is about cars where a dealer can have several brands and in several countries.
For example:
Dealer: John Doe 
has the brands Audi in UK, and Kia in France.

I have the below models: 
- Brand
- Country
- Dealer
- BrandsCountriesDealers (which links the above three together)

The dealer cannot add / edit a brand or a country. He can only add/edit/delete a car in the country that he has access to and to the brand that he owns.

I was wondering if I use a specific foreign key of the BrandsCountriesDealers model as an ACO only and when the dealer adds a car, I check if this car's brand and country are valid by checking the record in the BrandsCountriesDealers model which he has access to ?

I hope this was clear.

Comment: I usually use [Tiny](http://ww.dereuromark.de/2011/12/18/tinyauth-the-fastest-and-easiest-authorization-for-cake2/) to set the basic role access and use the controller for specific record based checks (UID == $record[user_id] etc).

Answer (score 0):

Implementing ACL is a bit hard but not impossible. Once you get use to working with ACL you undrestand how easy and powerful it is. It might take some research to configure and learn it but it is really worthed.

I think you should use ACL for certain reasons:

1. It makes your code very clean and tidy:

> You don't need to keep assign
>
> ```
>    if user logged in do this
>
>    or if user type is this do that
> ```

1. Access Level: No need to write validation for each types of user.
2. High Security: ACL is working with Auth component
3. each method can be granted to one or more user type (Role)
4. Almost every thing is stored in DB so your code is clear again

I remember when I started to work with ACL I followed [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIjfwqqGRhs). It is in Portuguese language. I don't know this language but I followed step by step and get it worked.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIjfwqqGRhs